# How to add additional attributes to RestKit Mapping that are not in JSON

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I have implemented a Restkit mapping to core data that contains an attribute of 'timestamp'.  My local data model supports 'day', 'month', and 'year' integer attributes that I need to populate using the timestamp from JSON. I am not sure where and how to do this.

My Mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping *mediaMapping = [[VSObjectStore shared] mappingForEntityForName:@"Media"];
    [mediaMapping setIdentificationAttributes:@[@"id"]];

    // Remove any relationships
    NSMutableArray *mediaMethods = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[_VSMedia propertyNames]];
    [mediaMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:mediaMethods];
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You might want to include details of what version of RestKit you're using. And details of what the timestamp is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your data model (or at least your approach). Store an `NSDate` instance in your model - it is the most accurate and well supported choice. Then the mapping should happen automatically. If you still want your 3 properties for day, month and year, fine, but make them derived (transient) and get them when required (or of fetch / save) from the `NSDate` timestamp.

Comment: I ultimately removed the additional attributes from my model and am using compound predicates to get what I need instead of pulling day, month, year separately.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the `RKObjectLoaderDelegate` following method:

`- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)loader willMapData:(inout id *)mappableData;`

This method is called after parsing the data but before mapping. Thus you could modify the data to add day, month and year.

The code will look something like this:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)loader willMapData:(inout id *)mappableData
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mediaData = *mappableData;
    // parse timestamp here
    [mediaData setObject:day forKey:@"day"];

}
```

and add the key to your mapping list:

```
NSMutableArray *mediaMethods = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[_VSMedia propertyNames]];

[mediaMethods addObject:@"day"]



[mediaMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:mediaMethods];
```

Comment: I am sure this methodology would work, but I am going to have to accept @Wain answer because I think he is right about changing the model instead.